# function trouble not in scope: data constructor

Tags: haskell

I am trying to write a function `removeSpaces` that once handed a string it will remove any spaces found within it.
What I got so far is:

```
import Data.Char
removeSpaces :: [Char] -> [Char]
removeSpaces [] = []
removeSpaces xs = filter isAlpha xs
```

This however keeps giving me the message "not in scope: data constructor" with the pieces of the string that are before and after any spaces within the `String`. Any help with this would be great.

Comment: It works for me, what version of what compiler/interpreter are you using and what is the exact output? Also `removeSpaces "Hello World!!11!" == "HelloWorld", which may not be what you want.

Answer (score 2):

That function  looks fine although you don't need the case for the empty list as
filter deals with that case.

```
import Data.Char
removeSpaces :: [Char] -> [Char]
removeSpaces xs = filter isAlpha xs
```

Can you give an example of how  you are calling  the function

Comment: I am calling the funnction as removeSpaces "no spaces" which should return nospaces, as I understand.

Comment: Are you using GHCi or are you just typing `removeSpaces "no spaces"` as a top level expression in your file?

Comment: Are you sure you have quotation marks around your string where you call it?

Comment: I go into the directory where the script is and use ghci then use :l a2 and type the command in.

Comment: It finally worked, it was somehow picking up an older version of the script. I just pasted it into a different file to get around that. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

It works fine:

```
$ echo "import Data.Char
> removeSpaces :: [Char] -> [Char]
> removeSpaces [] = []
> removeSpaces xs = filter isAlpha xs" > so.hs

$ ghci so.hs
GHCi, version 7.6.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( so.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
*Main> removeSpaces "no spaces"
"nospaces"
*Main>
```